# Overriding HTML CSS element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, photoswipe

I have recently added a Photoswipe gallery to my website which has the following CSS applied to it:

```
html {overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:auto;}
```

Now the problem is the full-screen gallery scrolls because of this overflow, but it should fit tight to the screen it's shown on, no scrolling. I don't want to remove it using jQuery as I was having problems with jQuery on this page.

I tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
html {}
</style>
```

With no luck. What else can I do to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for example:

```
<style type="text/css">
html 
{
overflow-y:auto !important;
overflow-x:auto !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: what would be better @riwette ?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou it's better to build website without any `!important`

Answer (score 0):

your css code snippet doesn't zero out the plugin's styles, it simple declares a new rule without any styles, you need to explicitly set the overflow values to something

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { 
       overflow-x:auto; 
       overflow-y:auto; 
    }
</style>
```

as long as this piece of code comes after the problem code, cascading should override the first styles, !important isn't needed (or a good practice).

also, you might want to play with the different values for overflow, since im not sure exactly how your plug-in works. possible values are visible, hidden, scroll, auto, inherit

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow